# java.lang.ClassCastException after D2 Install

Tags: java, documentum

After a fresh installation of D2 on windows 64 cs 7.1 tomcat, I get the following error when I try to save in D2-Config:

**jms log:**

```
15:09:35,078 ERROR [131] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-1) {}: java.lang.ClassCastException

15:09:35,079 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-1) 15:09:35,079 ERROR [http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-1] com.documentum.mthdservlet.DoMethod - Exception invoking com.emc.d2.api.methods.D2Method.

15:09:35,079 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-1) java.lang.ClassCastException

15:09:35,080 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/DmMethods].[DoMethod]] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet DoMethod threw exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException
    at com.documentum.mthdservlet.DoMethod.invokeMethod(Unknown Source) [mthdservlet.jar:]
    at com.documentum.mthdservlet.DoMethod.doPost(Unknown Source) [mthdservlet.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.
```

**D2-Config Log:**

> com.documentum.fc.common.DfException:     at
>   com.emc.d2.api.methods.D2Method.start(D2Method.java:431)
>   [D2-API-4.2.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.emc.d2.api.methods.D2Method.start(D2Method.java:239)
>   [D2-API-4.2.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.emc.d2.api.methods.D2Method.start(D2Method.java:219)
>   [D2-API-4.2.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.emc.d2.api.D2Session.getAdminTicket(D2Session.java:529)
>   [D2-API-4.2.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.emc.d2.web.servlets.D2Context.getAdminSession(D2Context.java:949)
>   [D2-Web-4.2.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.emc.d2.web.servlets.options.OptionsUtils.saveOptions(OptionsUtils.java:157) [OptionsUtils.class:na]   at
>   com.emc.d2.web.servlets.options.SaveOptions.processRequest(SaveOptions.java:65) [SaveOptions.class:na]    at
>   com.emc.d2.web.servlets.D2HttpServlet.execute(D2HttpServlet.java:233)
>   [D2-Web-4.2.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.emc.d2.web.servlets.D2HttpServlet.doGetAndPost(D2HttpServlet.java:421)
>   [D2-Web-4.2.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.emc.d2.web.servlets.D2HttpServlet.doPost(D2HttpServlet.java:127)
>   [D2-Web-4.2.0.jar:na]     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>   [servlet-api.jar:na]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>   [servlet-api.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.29]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.29]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.29]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.29]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [na:1.7.0_17]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [na:1.7.0_17]

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this question/answers](https://community.emc.com/message/805382) in EMC support forums. 
It looks like you are having wrong setup of PATH windows system variable. Read the installation guide, its priceless. ;)

Comment: Did follow the installation guide line by line.. but setting the class path and path according to the guide doesn't save them. Only keeps them in the current session. After setting them up it system properties it seems to be good.